# Adding "snooze" button to alarm clock with clearInterval(). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, audio, ecmascript-6, clearinterval

I've been working on an alarm clock 'app' project to practice JavaScript. I'm fairly new to it so maybe I'm just not understanding clearInterval() correctly, and I was hoping someone could help.

JavaScript:

```
let sound = new Audio('./music/alarmsound.mp3');
let playAudio = () => sound.play();
const snooze = document.getElementById('snooze');
let pause = () => sound.pause();

let alarm = document.getElementById('alarm');
alarm.onclick = function setAlarm() {
    let userHour = prompt("Please enter the hour of which you would like the alarm to be set ", "07");
    if (userHour.charAt(0) > 0 && userHour < 10) {
        userHour = "0" + userHour;
    }
    let userMinutes = prompt("Please enter the minutes of which you would like the alarm to be set ", "30");
    let timeformat = [userHour, userMinutes];
    function realTime() {
        let realtime = new Date();
        if(timeformat[0] == realtime.getHours() && timeformat[1] == realtime.getMinutes()) {
            playAudio();
        } 
        if(timeformat[0] != realtime.getHours && timeformat[1] != realtime.getMinutes()) {
            pause();
        }
    }
    let checkTime = () => {
        setInterval(realTime, 1000)
    }


checkTime();
let stopAlarm = () => {
    clearInterval(checkTime);
}
snooze.addEventListener("click", stopAlarm());
}
```

When the user clicks the alarm button, a prompt asks for them to set the hours, and then the minutes, that they want the alarm to go off. That part works. In addition, once one minute has passed and the current time no longer matches the alarm time set by the user, the audio stops. However, I'm trying to add a snooze button functionality and I can't seem to get it working no matter what I try.

Any tips and tricks are greatly appreciated! Sorry if the code is messy, like I said, I just started with JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thing are making this not work as you expect. Check the suggested changes, I've added comments.

```js
const snooze = document.getElementById('snooze');
const alarm = document.getElementById('alarm');
const sound = new Audio('./music/alarmsound.mp3');
const playAudio = () => sound.play();
const pause = () => sound.pause();
let intval; // 1. keep a reference to the interval outside of setAlarm()

alarm.onclick = function setAlarm() {
    let userHour = prompt("Please enter the...", "07");
    if (userHour.charAt(0) > 0 && userHour < 10) {
        userHour = "0" + userHour;
    }
    let userMinutes = prompt("Please enter the...", "30");
    let timeformat = [userHour, userMinutes];
    function realTime() {
        let realtime = new Date();
        if(timeformat[0] == realtime.getHours() && timeformat[1] == realtime.getMinutes()) {
            playAudio();
        } 
        if(timeformat[0] != realtime.getHours && timeformat[1] != realtime.getMinutes()) {
            pause();
        }
    }

    intval = setInterval(realTime, 1000) // 2. assign interval to the variable
}

// 3. Dont set your event listener inside the setAlarm() function (unless it's required)
function stopAlarm() {
   clearInterval(intval); // 4. Clear interval with correct reference
}
snooze.addEventListener("click", stopAlarm);
```